# Unsure of the condition for this loop (Pointer arithmetic)

Tags: c++

So I'm supposed to edit a bunch of code via requirements in the comments. I've gotten most of it but one part in particular has me stuck. It loops through as the original did, but I can't figure out what the condition of the loop should be and whatever I put just ends up crashing. I think it's something with sizeof? but nothing I try works. Any help would be appreciated!

Original:

```
int main()
{
const string ID_BASE = "56-123-";
// CHANGE STATIC ARRAY INTO DYNAMIC ARRAY.
const int NUM_PRODUCTS = 5;
Product products[NUM_PRODUCTS];
int i;

//cout << "Enter number of toys: ";
//cin >> numProducts;

   ....Code to fill products...

//ALTER LOOP TO USE ONLY POINTER OPERATIONS
// (NO SUBSCRIPTS).
for (i = 0; i < numProducts; i++)
{
    show(products[i]);
}
```

My changes:

```
int main()
{
const string ID_BASE = "56-123-";
// CHANGE STATIC ARRAY INTO DYNAMIC ARRAY.
int numProducts;
Product *products;
int i;

cout << "Enter number of toys: ";
cin >> numProducts;

products = new Product[numProducts];

...Code to fill products...

//ALTER LOOP TO USE ONLY POINTER OPERATIONS
// (NO SUBSCRIPTS).
for (Product *prodP = products;          ; *prodP++)
{
    show(*prodP);
}
```

Comment: Do not use dynamic arrays. Use vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it iterator style:

```
auto begin = products;
auto end = products + numProducts;
for( auto itr=begin; itr!=end; ++itr )
{
    show(*itr);
}
```

Comment: If you are using an ancient compiler, replace `auto` with `Product*`

Comment: This works, but we have not gone over iterators in class yet. A solution I came up with is to make an endPtr but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

`Product* endptr = products + numProducts;
for (Product* prodp = products; prodp != endptr; prodp++)`

Comment: Looks fine. You can also put `products + numProducts` directly in the condition, if you like, as in `prodp != products + numProducts`

Answer (score 1):

Condition:

```
prodP !=products+numProducts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something here, but when does the modified loop end??

```
for (Product *prodP = products;          ; *prodP++)
{
    show(*prodP);
}
```

there are only finite  elements, and I think you are over-running the array.

Profile with valgrind for these kind of errors/suspected errors.

Comment: If you read the question, it says `but I can't figure out what the condition of the loop should be` among other things